# AppendText method is not working

Tags: winforms, powershell

My PowerShell script function:

```
function Click {
    $outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,150) 
    $outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(565,200) 
    $outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
    $outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
    $Form.Controls.Add($outputBox) 

    $userid = $Emailid.text;
    $uid=[bool]($userid -as [Net.Mail.MailAddress])
    if($uid -eq "True")
    {
        $outputBox.Text = "Email id exists" 
    }
    else
    {
        $outputBox.Text = "Email id not exists" 
    }
    $owa = [bool](Get-CasMailbox $userid | fl owaenabled)
    if($owa -eq "True")
    {
        $outputBox.AppendText = " your email id has owa access" 
    }
    else
    {
        $outputBox.AppendText = "sorry... your email id has not owa access" 
    }
}
```

When my button is pressed above function is called, but I am only able to see last result into the `$outputBox`, but I want both the output in textbox. Also `ForegroundColor` is not working with it. It gives error, so how to use `ForegroundColor` with it?

Comment: Do you want to append each Text like $outputBox.Text += "YOUR TEXT `n"

Comment: If you want to concatenate two strings, use `+=` instead of assigning a new value with `=`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but  second text doesnot come into new line and also foreground color is not working with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AppendText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a **method**. You're using it like a **property**. Change this:

```
if($owa -eq "True")
{
    $outputBox.AppendText = " your email id has owa access"
}
else
{
    $outputBox.AppendText = "sorry... your email id has not owa access"
}
```

into this:

```
if($owa -eq "True")
{
    $outputBox.AppendText(" your email id has owa access")
}
else
{
    $outputBox.AppendText("sorry... your email id has not owa access")
}
```

As for the foreground color: you don't set that anywhere, and the property is named [`ForeColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez1ywchy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not `ForegroundColor`.

```
$outputBox.ForeColor = 'Red'
```